# 2nd order Ordinary differential equation, $ay'' + by' + cy = 0$, where $b$ is complex

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In particular my question was to solve this equation differentiated with respect to variable t:

$$\begin{cases}y'' + i K y' + \frac{M^2}{4} y  = 0\\ y(0) = 0\end{cases}$$

After solving with $e^{r t}$ I get $2$ complex roots:
$r =  \frac{i}{2} (K \pm \omega)$

where $\omega = \sqrt{K^2 + M^2}$

But I do not know how to proceed from there, because the wronskian is zero for $K = 0$ for all times $t$. Can anyone tell me the solution because I could not find it in the literature, see for example

https://www.math.purdue.edu/~wilker/Math266S01/Review4-S01.pdf

http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/ESSENTIAL%20CALCULUS/upfiles/topics/ess_at_08_solde_stu.pdf

Comment: https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Équation_différentielle_linéaire_d'ordre_deux that's in French and I don't see the corresponding English wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 1):

The function $y(t) = e^{rt}$ is a solution of your ODE iff $$r^2 + iKr + \frac{M^2}{4} = 0 \, .$$
Then $r_{\pm} = -\frac{i}{2}(K \pm \omega)$, where $\omega = \sqrt{M^2 + K^2}$ as you wrote. So all solutions of your ODE which satisfies the initial condition $y(0) = 0$ are the functions $y(t)= \alpha (e^{r_{-} t} - e^{r_+ t})$ where $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ is arbitrary.

As far as I see it is not necessary to invoke the Wronskian since the ODE is homogeneous.

Answer (score 0):

the general solution is
$$y=C_1\cos(\frac{1}{2}(K+w)t)+C_2\sin(\frac{1}{2}(K+w)t)$$
at $y(0)=0$
$$0=C_1+0$$
$$C_1=0$$
$$y=C_2\sin(\frac{1}{2}(K+w)t)$$